# AngularJS with velocity

Tags: javascript, angularjs, velocity.js

How to get the value of an html element using his id, withoud using ng-model

I try to get data to my page with velocity and i set this value to textarea, i take possiblity to user to modify the content of this element, for this i get well my data.

The problem is when user modify the contents of elements, how to get modification with angularjs

I try like this

```
<textarea class="form-control" id="description" rows="2" data="" ng-model="demand.description" placeholder="">
   $demand.description
</textarea>
```

on the screen i dont seen the value of textarea

Comment: Well, ng-model is clearly the angular way of doing that. Why don't you want to use it?

Comment: It dosn't work, i want firstly displayed on the screen the value of $demand.description, secondely detect if there is some change and get the new values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved the problem with this maner, its not very good, but that what i have now

```
 $scope.validateModification = function(){

    $scope.demand.description = $('#description').val();
    alert ($scope.demand.description);
    //after i sent the $scope.Demand to server
 }


 <textarea name="description" id="description">$demand.description</textarea>
```